# Kendo Stacked Column Chart grouping error

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have data like this

[image]

And here is my Json data format

```
[{  "Value1":"B95 ",
"Value2":1.2600,
"ChartType":"column",
"ChartDescription":"Fuel Sales Quantity",
"Value3":"2015-07-27",
"SeriesField":"Value2",
"CategoryField":"Value3",
"IsGroup":true,
"IsStacked":true,
"GroupValue":"Value1",
"SortValue":"Value3"},

{"Value1":"B93",
"Value2":8.2100,
"ChartType":"column",
"ChartDescription":"Fuel Sales Quantity",
"Value3":"2015-07-22",
"SeriesField":"Value2",
"CategoryField":"Value3",
"IsGroup":true,
"IsStacked":true,
"GroupValue":"Value1",
"SortValue":"Value3"}]
```

I just want to create a grouped stacked charts per day with kendo column charts
but when i draw this chart i have 6 unique day but chart show just 4 day 
 The chart example here...
[image]

Data mixed or shifting each other...

Here is my Javascript code

```
function createChart(number) {
$("#chart-" + number).kendoChart({
    dataSource: myData,
    title: {
        text: title
    },
    legend: {
        visible: true,
        position: "bottom",
        labels: {
            template: '#: chartType == "pie" ? dataItem.Value1 : chartType == "donut" ? dataItem.Value1 : text #'
        }
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: chartType,
        stack: stackValue
    },
    series: series,
    valueAxis: {
        labels: {
            format: "{0}"
        }
    },
    categoryAxis: categories,
    tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        format: "{0}",
        template: "#= dataItem.Value1 #: #= kendo.format('{0:N}',value)  #"
    }
});
```

}

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../Dashboards/QuerySelected',
        data: { id: number, from: fromdate, to: todate, fleet: fleetident },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length != 0) {
                    if (data[0].IsGroup) {
                        myData = {
                            data: data,
                            group:{
                                field: data[0].GroupValue
                            },
                            sort: {
                                field: data[0].SortValue,
                                dir: "asc"
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    else {
                        myData = data
                    }

                    series = [{
                        field: data[0].SeriesField
                    }];

                    categories = {
                        field: data[0].CategoryField
                    }
                    stackValue = data[0].IsStacked;
                    chartType = data[0].ChartType;
                    title = data[0].ChartDescription;

                    createChart(number);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Is it possible to my erroe on grouping or sorting on chart ??
How can i solve this problem 
Thanx
Saul

Comment: Can you add the zero values for each day: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/UsAho

Comment: Hi @ezanker i dont understand where i add zero value?

Comment: @ezanker I'm getting data from sql server . Do you have another solution  because chart will be dynamic from query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transform the data the data in javascript to look like this:

```
[
    {"Category": "2015-08-10", "B93": 1.2500, "DIESEL": 1.6, "B95": 0 },
    {"Category": "2015-08-06", "B93": 0, "DIESEL": 1.68, "B95": 0 }
]
```

One way to do it is:

```
  var ToolTipTemplate = "#= dataItem.Value1 #: #= kendo.format('{0:N}',value)  #";
  if (data.length != 0) {
    if (data[0].IsGroup) {
      var uniqueGroups = [];
      var transformedData = [];
      series = [];

      myData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: data,
            group: {
                field: data[0].GroupValue
            },
      });
      myData.fetch(function () {
          var v = this.view();
          for (var i=0; i<v.length; i++){
            uniqueGroups.push(v[i].value)
            series.push({
              name: v[i].value,
              field: v[i].value,
              categoryField: "Category",
            });
          }                
       });

      myData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: data,
        group: {
          field: data[0].SortValue
        },
        sort: {
          field: data[0].SortValue,
          dir: "asc"
        },
      });

      myData.fetch(function () {
        var v = this.view();
        for (var i=0; i<v.length; i++){
          var dataPoint = {"Category": v[i].value};
          for (var j=0; j<uniqueGroups.length; j++){
            dataPoint[uniqueGroups[j]] = 0;
          }
          for (var k=0; k<v[i].items.length; k++){
            dataPoint[v[i].items[k][v[i].items[k].GroupValue]] = v[i].items[k][v[i].items[k].SeriesField];
          }
          transformedData.push(dataPoint);            
        } 
      });

      console.log(transformedData);
      myData = transformedData;

      ToolTipTemplate = "#= series.name #: #= kendo.format('{0:N}',value)  #";          

    }
    else {
      myData = data
      series = [{
        field: data[0].SeriesField
      }];

      categories = {
        field: data[0].CategoryField
      }

    }
```

**[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/uNAme)**

Comment: Hi @ezanker i'm binding data with ajax but my chart cannot drawing do you have any suggession for this?

Comment: My data is coming properly.. legend and x-axis shows true values but series not shown.. I tried the refresh and redraw functions but its not showing data again??

Comment: @saulyasar, hard to say without seeing your code.  Are you recreating the chart on each AJAX success? or are you setting the dataSource of the existing chart?

Comment: Hi @ezanker You can check from here my all script i'm not using any html just using appends https://jsfiddle.net/akro3vy0/

Comment: I'm using this script with the same json data  but its not showing chart?? where is my fault? I ate 3 days for this @ezanker

Comment: @saulyasar it looks like a dashboard using multiple window widgets each containing a chart or grid... Here is a simplified version with fake AJAX calls and it still seems to work: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/EVuTA  I can't see anything too obviously wrong with your code.

Comment: Yes @ezanker I have table from db and i'm creating kendo window inside chart with number of that db rows. I'm using this with AJAX The strange thing is when i use fake data... chart is loading but i'm trying load dynamic data and its not working

Comment: I'm suspected about transforming data format because i'm always showing series with Value2 means numbers but in your example you are pushing series inside Value1 ... Value1 is name of data Value2 is value of data Value 3 is Category like time range I hope this info is enough for you @ezanker

Comment: @saulyasar when you look in the console at console.log(transformedData); Does it look correct? You need to put breakpoints and debug your script either via your IDE or chrome developer tools:  https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: yes that data looks correct because it returns data format as you give in answer..

Comment: Unfrotunately @ezanker data is true and valid but kendo cannot draw my chart i know how to debug on browser but its not drawing i'm suspected about any kendo error...

Comment: After that i transform my query pivot and unpivot and get the true values now chart is working @ezanker